# Делаю автобег для DayZ Standalone, хочу имитировать нажатие клавиши вперед

Tags: python, pyautogui

Делаю автобег для игры DayZ Standalone пробую имитировать нажатия клавиши "W", но в самой игре оно не работает(Вне игры, в блокноте, оно работает хорошо). Имитирую нажатия с помощью библиотеки pyautogui.
Как я могу сделать так, что-бы эти виртуальные нажатия распостранялись и на игру?
Вот мой код:

```
import pyautogui
import time



pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True
time.sleep(6)


pyautogui.press('w', presses=3)
print("End")
```

Comment: Возможно, в игре нажатия будут нестабильными, тогда можно попробовать отсылать через ScanCode: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/c3c0d72a2ec9446f79645638e69244ba5a89d126/press_release_keys__ScanCodes__for_games.py#L222

Answer (score 1):

`press` это нажатие и сразу отпускание клавиши. Вам нужно `pyautogui.keyDown('w')`

Comment: Попробовал, всеравно не работает:/ походу игра блокирует. Может можно это как-то обойти?

Comment: https://geekbrains.ru/posts/python_key_simulation посмотрите может что поможет

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте это.

```
import time
import keyboard

time.sleep(3) # Время что бы открыть игру

keyboard.press("W") # Зажимаем клавишу
time.sleep(5) # Время, которое перонаж должен бежать
keyboard.release("W") # Отжимаем клавишу
```

Ваш код - слишком быстро нажимает на клавиши, некоторые игры этого не любят и блочат эту кнопку пока вы не перестанете по ней кликать